# Bitbucket - permission denied (public key)

Tags: git

I have repos in github and bitbucket.

First I wanted to use same public key in bb and gh with no luck.

So I created another public key, my .ssh/config file look like this:

```
Host bb
    HostName bitbucket.org
    User hg
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile C:/Documents and Settings/Marek/.ssh/bb

Host github
    HostName github.com
    User git
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile C:/Documents and Settings/Marek/.ssh/id_rsa
```

bb.pub is for bitbucket. I pasted key from this file to bitbucket.

I still having

> Permission denied (public key)

when I try to push my initial commit. Could somebody help?

**HELP**

Answer (score 5):

You should always use "git" and "hg" as the usernames for github and bitbucket, and not your own username. The public key itself will be used to identify you.

Comment: And this is likely his issue.  Mine are 'hg' and 'git'.

Comment: It's just won't work, btw I found totally different conf example: https://confluence.atlassian.com/download/attachments/221449711/ssh_original_comments.pdf?version=1&modificationDate=1325525383067 WTF?

Comment: I am not sure that I get this answer. Can someone explain what we mean by `use "git" and "hg" as the usernames`? This is the very first time I am facing this `Permission denied (public key)` issue, and I never paid attention to the name of my ssh users...

Comment: The answer is confusing because OP edited the question afterwards; he originally used "someuser" as the user, implying it was his own username. For implementation reasons, Github, BB, and git/hg-hosting solutions like Gitolite or Gitlab, let all ssh clients connect under to a special service account (typically named "git" or "hg"), and only enforce ACLs afterwards based on the identity of the key. This of course doesn't apply if you are hitting a repository on a system on which you have a full ssh account.